# Generating Gauss-Seidel hard system

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I am writing various Gauss-Seidel algorithm parallel implementations using different programming techniques for my assignment.

I have created a MATLAB script for generating strictly diagonally dominant matrices with different degree of diagonal dominance and sparseness for testing my implementations.

Problem is that I can't find a way to generate matrix that requires more than 15 iterations to converge (epsilon is set to 0.0001).

Is there a property that makes a system GS-hard?

Comment: Probably you should consider asking this on [SciComp](http://www.scicomp.stackexchange.com). However, I would probably suggest looking at spectral properties including Condition Numbers.

Comment: If you mention the Hilbert matrix, people will think that you know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A matrix with a high condition number will do the trick. One way  to construct such a matrix is to create a diagonal matrix with a huge first entry and a tiny last entry and multiply it from both sides by random orthonormal matrices. The latter you can get by doing a QR decomposition of a random matrix.

Comment: In a pinch, QR decomposing a random matrix to generate a random orthogonal matrix works. There are [more efficient methods](http://link.aip.org/link/?SJNAAM/17/403/1) (and equivalent), though...